# How does rap scoring work on singstar

Tags: singstar

I like singstar. I am not a great singer, but the bio feedback look helps me to correct myself and see how I have gone wrong.

However with rap scoring, I have no idea how it works, or how to improve my score. The little beat thingy in the corner seems to randomly decide great or awful although I can’t discern any difference I what I am doing. Does anyone have an idea how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an article found [here](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/6453990):

> Rap sections use a combination of speech recognition and rhythm detection.

Essentially, not only do you have to get the timing right, but the words have to "sound" correct, too. Try enunciating your words as clearly as possible so that the audio recognition software can interpret you better.